# How to add trace id to tracing log by spring boot 3 rsocket?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing, spring-boot-rsocket

I try to upgrade spring boot from 2.7 to 3.0. and the project use rsocket. I was use `Spring Cloud Sleuth` to get trace id into log file. and upgrade to spring boot 3, change to use `io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing`.

how do I add trace log into log4j2?

log4j2 pattern:

`%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%X{traceId:-}][%X{spanId:-}][%p][%X{xmlName}][%t] - %msg%n`

spring boot version: `3.0.5`

and io.micrometer version: `1.0.3`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

these are all dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rsocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- rsocket security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-rsocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- r2dbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  r2dbc 连接池 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--r2dbc mysql 库-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jasync-sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasync-r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rsocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>rsocket-micrometer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Kindly try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75268665/micrometer-tracing-does-not-include-the-trace-id-in-the-log

Comment: @JCompetence, thank you. I try to use it, but not working.

Comment: u can try with Tracer class, by manually injecting traceId and put to socket headers

Answer (score 1):

after lots of research, this is the only thing that worked for me (hope it works for u too):

just remove the:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

and make sure to have these two dependency instead:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @Seyed, I try to remove `micrometer-tracing` but it still not work for me.

Comment: @J.Hu did u replace it with micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave?

Comment: Yes, I post my new pom.xml setting below.

Comment: @J.Hu please edit the old one and add your updates instead of a posting an answer

Comment: already updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(spring-boot 3.1.3)

```
logging:
  pattern:
    level: '[${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId},%X{spanId}]'
```